# Code behind isn't finding radio buttons after postback

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, postback, viewstate

I have a survey page, where i insert radio buttons dinamically in form load event. When i click the button to send the results, after postback, the radio buttons are still there, with the checked state correctly. But if i do some code, in the code behind, that tries to check if one of them is checked (by FindControl(id)), the page crashes. I can´t do debug, so i don't know what error is.

---

```
<%@ Control language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Explicit="True" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="USER" Src="~/Admin/Skins/User.ascx" %>
<style>
body {background-image:none; background-color:transparent;}
</style>
<div style="float:left; width:420px; height:335px;" id="divPerguntas" enableviewstate="true" runat="server"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:420px; height:75px;"><asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="/Portals/_default/Skins/AdWin/img/Enviar.png" id="imgEnviar" runat="server" style="cursor:pointer;" /></div>

<div id="ContentPane" runat="server"></div>

<script runat="server">
    Protected Sub EnviarClick() Handles imgEnviar.Click

        Dim conexao As SqlConnection
        Dim comando As SqlCommand
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "SELECT S.SurveyID, SO.SurveyOptionID FROM AdWin_Demo.dbo.Surveys S INNER JOIN AdWin_Demo.dbo.SurveyOptions SO ON S.SurveyID = SO.SurveyID WHERE S.VideoId = " + Request.QueryString("id") + " ORDER BY S.ViewOrder, SO.ViewOrder"
        conexao = New SqlConnection("#CONNECTIONSTRING#")
        conexao.Open()
        comando = New SqlCommand(sql, conexao)

        myReader = comando.ExecuteReader

        If myReader.HasRows Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(myReader)
            Dim SurveyID As Integer = 0
            Dim FirstQuestion As Boolean = True
            Dim checkedGroup As Boolean = False
            Dim insertList As New DataTable
            Dim ColumnIDSurveyOption As New DataColumn("c", GetType(Integer))
            insertList.Columns.Add(ColumnIDSurveyOption)
            Dim row As DataRow


            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                If FirstQuestion Then
                    SurveyID = dr("SurveyID")
                    FirstQuestion = False
                End If
                If SurveyID <> dr("SurveyID") Then
                    SurveyID = dr("SurveyID")
                    checkedGroup = False
                End If
                If SurveyID = dr("SurveyID") And checkedGroup = False Then
                        Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())
                        If radiobuttonToCheck.Checked Then
                        checkedGroup = True
                        row = insertList.NewRow()
                        row("insertList") = dr("SurveyOptionID")
                        insertList.Rows.Add(row)
                        End If
                End If
            Next

            If checkedGroup = True Then
                Dim dnnUserCtrl As New DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController
                For Each dr As DataRow In insertList.Rows
                    sql = "INSERT INTO AdWin_Demo.dbo.Adwin_RespostasDadas (IDUser, SurveyOptionID) SELECT " & dnnUserCtrl.GetCurrentUserInfo.UserID & ", " & dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString()
                    comando = New SqlCommand(sql, conexao)
                    myReader = comando.ExecuteReader
                Next
            Else
                Response.Write("Nao respondeste a tudo")
            End If
        End If

        myReader.Close()
        conexao.Close()


    End Sub
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.EnableViewState = True

        'If Not Page.IsPostBack Then


        Dim conexao As SqlConnection
        Dim comando As SqlCommand
        Dim myReader As SqlDataReader
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "SELECT S.SurveyID, S.Question, SO.OptionName, SO.SurveyOptionID FROM AdWin_Demo.dbo.Surveys S INNER JOIN AdWin_Demo.dbo.SurveyOptions SO ON S.SurveyID = SO.SurveyID WHERE S.VideoId = " + Request.QueryString("id") + " ORDER BY S.ViewOrder, S.SurveyID, SO.ViewOrder"
        conexao = New SqlConnection("#CONNECTIONSTRING#")
        conexao.Open()
        comando = New SqlCommand(sql, conexao)

        myReader = comando.ExecuteReader


        If myReader.HasRows Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.Load(myReader)
            Dim SurveyID As Integer = 0
            Dim FirstQuestion As Boolean = True
            Dim ActualDiv As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl

            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                If SurveyID = dr("SurveyID") Then

                    Dim rb As New RadioButton
                    rb.GroupName = "Group" & SurveyID.ToString()
                    rb.ID = dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString()
                    rb.Text = dr("OptionName").ToString()
                    rb.EnableViewState = True
                    ActualDiv.Controls.Add(rb)
                    ActualDiv.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br/>"))

                Else
                    SurveyID = dr("SurveyID")

                    If FirstQuestion = False Then
                        Dim hr2 As New HtmlGenericControl("hr")
                        divPerguntas.Controls.Add(hr2)
                    End If

                    Dim div As New System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV")
                    div.Style.Add("float", "left")
                    div.Style.Add("width", "400px")
                    div.Style.Add("color", "#777")
                    div.Style.Add("font-size", "11px")
                    div.Style.Add("line-height", "15px")
                    divPerguntas.Controls.Add(div)
                    ActualDiv = div

                    ActualDiv.InnerText = dr("Question").ToString()
                    ActualDiv.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br/>"))

                    Dim rb As New RadioButton
                    rb.GroupName = "Group" & SurveyID.ToString()
                    rb.ID = dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString()
                    rb.Text = dr("OptionName").ToString()
                    rb.EnableViewState = True
                    ActualDiv.Controls.Add(rb)
                    ActualDiv.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br/>"))

                    FirstQuestion = False
                End If
            Next
            Dim hr As New HtmlGenericControl("hr")
            divPerguntas.Controls.Add(hr)
        End If

        myReader.Close()
        conexao.Close()

    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't do debug"?

Comment: I forget to mention, this is an ascx file, a dotnetnuke skin. I don't know how to do debug...

Comment: If you have another way that i could create the radios dinamically and then check if every group of radios has a selected radio, and send the IDs of those radios to the code behind so that i could store the info in the DB, i would thank you

Comment: Asp.Net has `<asp:RadioButtonList />` or something like that. I don't know if that could help you.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for the help
`Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())`
->
`Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = Me.FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())
```

->

```
Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = Me.FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add controls to the page in `PreInit` event and see if you can access data correctly. More details here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: I am not understanding. I forget to mention, this is an ascx file, a dotnetnuke skin. How should I do PreInit event? Visual Studio says it doens't exist when i chane 'Load' to 'PreInit'

Comment: Ok UC do not have preinit event, can you try with Init event.

Comment: With the init event, the radios disappear after postback

Comment: If you have another way that i could create the radios dinamically and then check if every group of radios has a selected radio, and send the IDs of those radios to the code behind so that i could store the info in the DB, i would thank you

Comment: Not skipping it... It's very strange. Do you want to see the code? I really need some help with this one...

Comment: You can paste your code on somewhere like pastebin.com. Also put a try catch block if you know where it is failing, and catch the error and show is somewhere on the UC

Comment: I edited the question, with the code. Already tried the try catch, but DNN hides the error. Only shows this: "500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

Comment: Where are you adding `ActualDiv` to the UC Control collection? there should a line like this.Controls.Add(ActualDiv)

Comment: `divPerguntas.Controls.Add(div)
ActualDiv = div`

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for the help
`Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())`
->
`Dim radiobuttonToCheck As RadioButton = Me.FindControl(dr("SurveyOptionID").ToString())`